# Embeddings of spherical Kac-Moody varieties?

Tags: reference-request, ag.algebraic-geometry

There is a well established theory of embeddings $G/H \to X$ into a normal variety $X$ where $G$ is a reductive group over an algebraically closed field and the image of any Borel $B$ is open in $X$; that standard reference is [Knop](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.123.5844&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

I wonder if there is similar theory when $G$ is replaced by a Kac-Moody group.  I'm most interested in the case the group is a loop group.

Comment: Spherical Kac-Moody varieties in general I do not know, but there is a nice theory of (the subclass of) Kac-Moody symmetric spaces. See e.g. arXiv:0712.2320v1 [math.RA] and arXiv:1003.4435v1 [math.DG] as  starting points. 